# How to avoid flickering in Graphical drawings using X11

Tags: c++, linux, x11, embedded-linux, xlib

We are drawing graph in a window. We are updating the curves for every 50ms
with the values received from hardware say like sensors.
We need to display the values in graphical format. So we are updating the
graph for every 50ms. This gives flickering issue.
We are writing the code in X11. Is there a way to avoid flickering in
graphical drawing in X11. Thanks in advance.

Comment: windowing library? Are you drawing directly to the screen? If so, why aren't you drawing to an off-screen buffer? One which is then blasted to the screen upon completion of drawing the curves for the current 50ms 'window'.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but already we draw the graph using bitmap and then copy to the window in that case also windows is flickering. We are doing this graphics in child window. We had created three child window with one root window. we are drawing graphs in child window. My doubt is whether we need to handle events, but now we didnt use any events

Comment: Answer too long for a comment - see added 'answer'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The keyword here is double-buffering. But I don't know if x11 offers this out-of-the-box or you need to implement it yourself, so I'll leave the google search for you ;)

Apart from that you may consider updating less often. Perhaps it's enough to update with a 250, 500 or 1000ms period? That depends on your use-case of course.

Answer (score 1):

You're welcome. Hmm. Well, in that case I'd check out the X-Server settings for the machines that will run it. I recently got a new vid card and found that openGL apps were running a higher number of frames/second, but that the quality was terrible - there was visible 'tearing' of the image - you could consistantly see a combination of the last and the current frames at the same time. After I enabled *wait for VSynch* in the XServer's settings, the problem dissapeared. However, it sounds more like a problem I've experienced under MS windows in the past. In that particular case, each time I sent a new image to the control, windows was redrawing the background of the window/dialog that was under the image window. So, instead of simply replacing the old image, it would erase the image to the stock-grey before then going on to replace the image (grrr). If you've got access to fast enough screen-recording software, you can video the app whilst running, then play back the video frame-by-frame. Alternatly, you may get some traction if you search for "disable window background redrawing/erasing X11" or something similar. :)

Guess it would also depend on whether or not you used Gtk+, wxWidgets or just raw X11 code.

Comment: We are using raw X11 code. We are using XCopyArea for drawing the pixmap to window. Whether we need to use XSync command in the code? where we need to do this.

Comment: Reading from the XCopyArea man page, I note with particular interest the text _"If regions of the source rectangle are obscured and have not been retained in backing store or if regions outside the boundaries of the source drawable are specified, those regions are not copied. Instead, the following occurs on all corresponding destination regions that are either visible or are retained in backing store. **If the destination is a window with a background other than None, corresponding regions of the destination are tiled with that background**"_ - I'd check the destination window's background.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. We are using XCopyArea with correct region. In our code we didnt set background as none. I tried to set the XSetBackgroundPixmap to none, but i didnt get the correct output, Instead the whole window is painted with the foreground color

Comment: You're most welcome. (sorry, I forgot to say that last time also) I'm really not at all familiar with X11, so I'm afraid that I'm  out of suggestions just now, sorry. :( I've bookmarked the question and will check back if I have any more ideas. :)